# How to boot from my Windows installation disk?

Tags: installation, boot, 13.10, windows

Here's a [Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1wfzg3/hi_i_would_like_to_know_how_to_boot_from_a/) detailing my problem a bit more. I can provide more information if needed.

Hi! I've installed Ubuntu as my OS because I needed a working OS to get a new Windows disk.
I've already referred to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) thread for help, but I get stuck on the actually installing Windows part; my computer skips over booting from my Windows CD while it can boot from my Ubuntu Live CD just fine. Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Windows? If Win8 or Win8.1, is UEFI enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your boot order.  When you first turn on your computer your first screen will show a brand name (usually the brand name of the motherboard in your computer).

From that screen you should see a list of options at the bottom in one of those options should lead you to change the boot order of your computer. You will want your "CD/DVD" option to be the first option.